# Why Nav bar list not on right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am having an issue when I remove navbar toggler button and div navbar collapse my whole navbar elements are on the right the way i want them to be, but that div navbar collapse is their to make navbar responsive to look navbar good, my whole nav lists go on the side of my brand logo.
Please help me how do i fix? and I am using bootstrap.

#### HTML/Bootstrap:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" data-toggle="affix" >
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
    
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav"> 
    
            <ul class="navbar navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Members</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Membership</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                
            </ul>
             </div> 
        </div>
    </nav>
```

#### CSS:

```
*{ 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
} 

nav { 
    letter-spacing: 4px; 
    font-family: 'Metal Mania', cursive; 
} 

.navbar {
    -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s ease; 
    -moz-transition:padding 0.2s ease; 
    -o-transition:padding 0.2s ease; 
    transition:padding 0.2s ease; } 

.affix { 
    padding-top: 0.2em !important; 
    padding-bottom: 0.2em !important; 
    -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s linear; 
    -moz-transition:padding 0.2s linear; 
    -o-transition:padding 0.2s linear; 
    transition:padding 0.2s linear; 
}
```

Comment: Post your CSS and we'll get to it :D

Comment: this is the css only which i am using , everything else is bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Fixed!
Fixed my issue by giving ml-auto to ul.
Thanks Everyone who tried to answwer

Comment: Could you provide the working code by editing this answer? It may help people in the future who may come across the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.collapse` class from div

```
<div class="navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" data-toggle="affix" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav"> 

        <ul class="navbar navbar-nav ">
            <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Members</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Membership</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item p-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

        </ul>
         </div> 
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it did not work, I am trying to make whole nav list to go to right, not with the website logo